# create custom AMI for multinode cluster in aws

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I'm newbie to AWS. I'm supposed to create an customized AMI from which a hadoop cluster should be setup on creation of those specified no of instances.

WorkAround: I know how to create AMI from the console but using that AMI I cant setup the cluster..!
And I went through cloudFormation template but I'm unable to integrate this template with the newly created AMI.

Please help me:

- can we call the stack(template) while creating instances using AMI..?
- can we establish hadoop cluster setup using the AMI or CloudFormation template or stacks or anything..?

NOte: we aren't supposed to use EMR for this operation.

Comment: Do you have any prior experience in creating Hadoop clusters? Why can't use use EMR -- it does it all for you automatically?

Comment: you normally don't built the AMI and do the cloud formation in one single step. once you have the AMI you should be able to put that in the CF template. what issues are you seeing?

Comment: @John Rotenstein :Yes I've experience in it. In fact there's a script, to which slave IPs to be passed as parameters, will take care of hadoop installation and setup. We cant use EMR. As of now, all we know is we've to use concept of AMI and CloundFormation we can achieve our goals but we dont know how to use them or there may be some other ways..?

Comment: @ Mircea : I didn't understand your first point. If i've the AMI, how can I put CF template in it..?Please explain in detail

Comment: Why can't you use EMR?